# IF Performance with changing condition style

Tags: c++, performance

I have this code

```
void test()
{
        If (condition)
        {
              doSomthing();
        }
}

test();
doSomethingMore();
```

Is there any performance effect with change it to:

```
void test()
{
        If (!condition)
        {
              return;
        }else
              doSomthing();
        }
}

test();
doSomethingMore();
```

**Why**??

Comment: The answer to all performance questions here boils down to "Implement both, and measure".

Comment: Is this supposed to be C++ code ?

Comment: Looks like PHP to me. Even then, it's broken.

Comment: Have you measured the performance of both? How did you get this to compile? This doesn't look like C++.

Comment: @Paul: looks more like pseudo-code to me...

Comment: It's been edited now and it looks slightly more like C++, but there is still the use of `If` and the unmatched braces, so it's still broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're really asking the wrong question. The performance is completely irrelevant here. Any optimizing compiler will render it absolutely insignificant, probably producing *exactly* the same binary for both styles.

No, in fact the *real* question is which code snippet is more **readable**. Your fellow human beings are the ones who will have to read and understand your code later. And, if you're particularly unlucky, one of those human beings that will have to read and understand your code later might even be *you*. Thus, it's *far* more important to write code that is logically structured and easily readable than it is to worry about micro-optimizations like this. Let the compiler handle those.

So, which is more readable? Definitely the first one. If the `condition` is true, then you're going to call the `doSomething()` function. Far more understandable.

In general, `if` statements should evaluate positively-named conditions. Most of the time, you should try to avoid the `!` sign, as it's easily missed when scanning the code and can potentially make your code read as a double-negative. You also should generally avoid having multiple exit points from functions (i.e., the `return` statement). You should be able to read the function from top-to-bottom and see exactly what it does, without having to jump around. The second code snippet violates *both* of these rules, and does little else to help justify preferring it over the first.

Comment: @LightWing - Especially bad is combining `if(!condition)` with an `else` as you then **have** a double negation for that part.

Answer (score 2):

For any modern compiler its extremely unlikely that small changes like this would make any difference. The optimizer already does many small optimizations (and several large ones).

In your particular example there will definitely be no difference even with an totally  unoptimized compiler. All you have done is added an extra explicit "return" instruction which will sometimes be executed instead of the implied return at the end of the function.

Your code may end up four bytes bigger but the execution time would be identical.